# Adding information using DbContext - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

I'm sittin' with my final project on the school, but have some trouble finishing it.

First of all I have made a Webstore with help from following [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1). It's a tutorial based on MVC 3, but I made it for newest version.

Afterwards I wanted to make some kind of blog-post database based on the same principles and this is where I'm in trouble.

I have made the Article as a model:

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string MainText { get; set; }
    public string PictureURL { get; set; }
    public ArticleSubject ArticleSubject { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards I created the ArticleSubject:

```
public class ArticleSubject
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I created the NewsEntities DbContext:

```
public class NewsEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleSubject> ArticleSubjects { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I filled following in to a "NewsData" class:

```
public class NewsData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NewsEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(NewsEntities context)
    {
        var articleSubjects = new List<ArticleSubject>
        {
            new ArticleSubject { Title = "Almindelige Nyheder" },
            new ArticleSubject { Title = "Arrangementer" },
            new ArticleSubject { Title = "Udstillinger" }
        };
    }
}
```

Then I created a NewsManagerController using Entity Framework. When I run my application, and will create a new articles the Subject-dropdown is empty. I have been looking all night for a solution without any luck.

I hope you can help me out! Feel free to ask for more code snippets or information.

Thanks!

//refnedergaard

EDIT:

Controller:

```
public class NewsManagerController : Controller
{
    private NewsEntities db = new NewsEntities();

    // GET: NewsManager
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var articles = db.Articles.Include(a => a.ArticleSubject);
        return View(articles.ToList());
    }

    // GET: NewsManager/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
        if (article == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(article);
    }

    // GET: NewsManager/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.ArticleSubjects, "SubjectId", "Title");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: NewsManager/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ArticleId,SubjectId,Title,MainText,PictureURL")] Article article)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Articles.Add(article);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.ArticleSubjects, "SubjectId", "Title", article.SubjectId);
        return View(article);
    }

    // GET: NewsManager/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
        if (article == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.ArticleSubjects, "SubjectId", "Title", article.SubjectId);
        return View(article);
    }

    // POST: NewsManager/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ArticleId,SubjectId,Title,MainText,PictureURL")] Article article)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.ArticleSubjects, "SubjectId", "Title", article.SubjectId);
        return View(article);
    }

    // GET: NewsManager/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
        if (article == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(article);
    }

    // POST: NewsManager/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Article article = db.Articles.Find(id);
        db.Articles.Remove(article);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Create-view:

```
    @model boerglumklosterdk.Models.Article

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Article</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubjectId, "SubjectId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("SubjectId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubjectId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MainText, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MainText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MainText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PictureURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PictureURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PictureURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the relevant action method and view code for the create form

Comment: What _Subject-dropdown_ You need to show the relevant code (the controller and the view)

Comment: I have added the controller and the create view to the post. Thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is because you are not saving to your DB your list of `ArticleSubject`. You need to add them first the `ArticleSubjects`  DbSet and them call `SaveChanges` method of your context:

```
context.ArticleSubjects.AddRange(articleSubjects);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now, if you use [Migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx), you are not going to drop your DB in case that your model change, so you might want to use the @Sam variant to avoid duplicates.

Also, in order to execute your custom initializer, you have to set the DB `Initializer` via `Database` property:

```
public class NewsEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArticleSubject> ArticleSubjects { get; set; }

    public NewsEntities()
    {
      Database.SetInitializer(new NewsData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried the "@sam way" and added your public NewsEntities() brackets. I didn't get any out of it. When I tried with breakpoint and step-by-step it never showed med NewsData.cs for some reason.

Comment: NOW! I used the 

context.ArticleSubjects.AddRange(articleSubjects);
context.SaveChanges()

So you were right only because I didn't saved the data.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You created a list of subjects to add to your context, but you never save the seed data into your context. You could try:

```
public class NewsData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NewsEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(NewsEntities context)
    {
        context.ArticleSubjects.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Title,
            new ArticleSubject { Title = "Almindelige Nyheder" },
            new ArticleSubject { Title = "Arrangementer" },
            new ArticleSubject { Title = "Udstillinger" }
        );
    }
}
```